# How can I use datetime with 70 minutes?

Tags: python, date, time

The problem occurs when the program reaches this line of code:

```
baggageDeliveryTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(baggageDeliveryTime, '%M')
```

When it reaches this line the program reads:

```
baggageDeliveryTime = datetime.datetime.strptime('70', '%M')
```

But the minutes go only up to 59.
So how can I modify the code below to use more than 59 minutes?

```
flight = ('TAP98', 'Rio de Janeiro', '09:55', '323', '467')

import doctest, sort, datetime

def baggageEndDeliveryTime(flight):
    """
    Time that the delivery of all baggage is complete.
    Requires: flight is a tuple with four elements.
    Ensures: string which represents the time when the delivery of all baggage is complete.
    """
    baggageNumber = int(flight[4])

    baggageStartDeliveryTime = flight[2]
    baggageStartDeliveryTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(baggageStartDeliveryTime, "%H:%M")
    baggageStartDeliveryTime = datetime.timedelta(hours = baggageStartDeliveryTime.hour, minutes = baggageStartDeliveryTime.minute)

    baggageDeliveryTime = str(baggageNumber * 30 / 200)
    baggageDeliveryTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(baggageDeliveryTime, '%M')
    baggageDeliveryTime = datetime.timedelta(hours = baggageDeliveryTime.hour, minutes = baggageDeliveryTime.minute)

    baggageEndDeliveryTime = baggageStartDeliveryTime +  baggageDeliveryTime
    baggageEndDeliveryTime = baggageEndDeliveryTime.seconds
    baggageEndDeliveryTime = '{:02}:{:02}'.format(baggageEndDeliveryTime // 3600, baggageEndDeliveryTime % 3600 // 60)

    return baggageEndDeliveryTime
```

Comment: what exactly is `baggageDeliveryTime = datetime.datetime.strptime('70', '%M')` supposed to do?

Comment: why are you using a datetime to hold a quantity of minutes? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ... maybe he wants 1/1/1900 @ 1.10am?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, guess we need marty mcfly and the doc to pick that bag up then ;)

Comment: I used datetime.strptime to parses a string into a time object. And then converted to timedelta format to subtract the times.

Answer (score 0):

```
 baggageDeliveryTime = datetime.datetime.strptime('0', '%M') + datetime.timedelta(seconds = 60 * 70)
```

maybe?

but really as pointed out in the comments you should probably just use a timedelta or maybe a datetime.time object

Answer (score 0):

Well... You doing it completely backward...

If you want to calculate the datetime corresponding to the end of you delivery time you made:
datetime of your plane hour of arrival + timedelta need to get baggage... Not a strangely calculated timedelta of your hour of arrival + datetime strangely calculate from the time needed for getting the baggage...

And datetime object have formating capacity...

```
def func(flight):
    nb_baggage = int(flight[4])

    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(flight[2], "%H:%M")
    delivery_time = datetime.timedelta(minutes=(nb_baggage * 30 / 200))
    end_time = start_time + delivery_time

    return end_time.strftime('%H:%M')
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html

Comment: Well I tested your code but I got the following error: "AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'format'"

Comment: oups... .strftime('%H:%M') (some mixing with '{0:%H:%M}'.format(start_time) format syntax in python3...)